# View expanding to image width in xCode storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

Just started with xCode 5 storyboard and am having an issue with images.  I have a View Controller that Houses a Scroll View > Image View.

When the image loads, it's displaying at full size and expanding the Scroll View. I've tried changing the View Mode and resizing it programmatically as shown below but it's not working.  Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

```
 if(!_curInfo.img)
    {
        showActivity(self);
        dispatch_queue_t aQueue1 = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(aQueue1, ^{
            _curInfo.img = getImageFromURL([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", g_serverUrl, _curInfo.imgPath]);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                hideActivity();
                [_imgCompany setImage:_curInfo.img];
            });
        });
    }

    _imgCompany.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,180);
    _imgCompany.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    _imgCompany.clipsToBounds=YES;
    [_imgCompany setImage:_curInfo.img];
```

Here is what it looks like
[image]

Comment: I have a fair exp with iOS but i always have trouble mixing scroll and autolayout. Disable autolayout and try...

Comment: try `_imgCompany.clipsToBounds=NO;`

Comment: Is the master switch for Auto Layout turned on in storyboard?

Comment: @bilobatum Yes, it is on.  I flipped it off and poof, success! If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
_imgCompany.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

or

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried both options and both yielded the same results. Any more ideas?

Comment: you can set autoresizingMask in scrollview or in file-owners Use Autolayout check mark off.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the master switch for Auto Layout switched on. Turn it off.